# Run GTM(Google Tag Manager) within Angular SPA

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I am building an Angular 6 SPA. When using Google Analytics, I am using the following code:

```
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'XXXXXXX', 'auto');    //tracking code
```

in `index.html`
Since I want to trigger analytics for every page inside `app.component.ts`, I have the following code:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
     (window as any).ga("set", "page", event.urlAfterRedirects);
        (window as any).ga("send", "pageview");
  }
}
```

So far, so good. The problem is with `Google Tag Manager`. Here is the code in index.html:

```
<script nonce="1234567890">
    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
            'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true;
        j.nonce = "1234567890"; j.src =
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'XXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

The above is running only `once` when Angular bootstraps. I cannot find a similar to the above way as to make it run again when Angular router navigated to another route. Any ideas?

Comment: This is essentially what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885180/can-anyone-help-implementing-nuxt-js-google-tag-manager/52885317#52885317

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone help implementing Nuxt.js Google Tag Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885180/can-anyone-help-implementing-nuxt-js-google-tag-manager)

Comment: Where did you get that gtm script? This doesn't look like the official one

Answer (score 0):

Running once is OK for GTM and SPA. Basic 'pageview' event in GTM corresponds to the actual page load so it only fires once with SPA. However, you may use GTM history events in GTM to fire GA pageview tags within your SPA application.
Here's the doc https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679322?hl=en