# nuxtjs/google-tag-manager only add google analytics when cookie consent has been given

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, nuxt.js, google-tag-manager

I'm currently trying to make my Tracking Opt-In. Meaning that before Google Analytics tracks the user, the user has to give consent. My website uses Nuxtjs and the @nuxtjs/google-tag-manager. In the nuxt-config.js I set it up like this `modules: [
    'nuxt-leaflet',
    '@nuxtjs/redirect-module',
    ['@nuxtjs/moment', { locales: ['de'], plugin: false }],
    ['@nuxtjs/sitemap', {
      path: '/sitemap.xml',
      generate: false,
      cacheTime: (1000 * 60 * 60), // generate every hour
      gzip: true,
      hostname: 'https://kreuzwerker.de',
      routes () {
        return generateSitemap()
      }
    }],
    ['@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager',
      {
        id: '/*GTM-Code*/',
        dev: true // to disable in dev mode
      }]
  ],`
and it works perfectly fine but now I want to connect it somehow to my Cookie Consent Form. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're using a deprecated nuxtjs module; use the new GTM module, right here; https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module.

In your config, make sure you've set the following:

```
gtm: {
  autoInit: false
}
```

Once you've gotten consent, in your form, call a callback function which calls the GTM init function; `$gtm.init('GTM-XXXXXXX')`.

Good luck, read the GitHub page it explains it all.

Comment: is there a way to also make the same happen with the old package? I can't update it because the new package doesn't support the NuxtJS version I'm using.

Comment: is there any change required in GTM for making this nuxt plugin work as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885180/can-anyone-help-implementing-nuxt-js-google-tag-manager/52885317

Comment: @SavinaChandla Yes, you need to setup the history change event & set a single tracker or make sure the referer/window location does not change on route change.