# How to send Page View Event to Google Tag Manager in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Until now, I was using Google Analytics directly and I was firing Page View Event manually with JavaScript from `app.component.ts`, like this:

```js
declare var gtag: Function;
...
constructor(private router: Router) {
  const navEndEvents = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  );
  navEndEvents.subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
    gtag('config', 'xxx', {
    page_path: event.urlAfterRedirects,
    page_title: event.urlAfterRedirects
    });
  })
}
```

Now, I want to use Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager, and not directly. How should I send Page View Event now?

Comment: I think you can simply push stuff on window.dataLayer?

Comment: You can follow a similar implementation as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885180/can-anyone-help-implementing-nuxt-js-google-tag-manager/52885317#52885317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with [angular-google-tag-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-tag-manager) package. Once you install and configure package, you can send whatever event to GTM really easy. Refactor for Page View Event in `app.component.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { GoogleTagManagerService } from 'angular-google-tag-manager';

constructor(private router: Router, private gtmService: GoogleTagManagerService) {
  const navEndEvents = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  );
  navEndEvents.subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
    this.gtmService.pushTag({ event: 'page', pageName: event.urlAfterRedirects });
  });
}
```

Comment: can it work without page refresh ?  i think your code will not work(fire gtm) without refresh the page, if yes work then what i do for that  because i have same code but without refreshing the page not working means not fire gtm, when i refresh the pag then fire gtm and show in google analytics .. any help ?

Comment: Yes, it should work without page refresh. I updated my answer. Can you try again? Previously, I used custom event name. Now, I updated it with standard one.